# Regex for keeping only letters and blank-space?

Tags: regex

This regex works fine for the word variable but it is removing all the white-space from the definition variable which is not wanted. Having trouble understanding why.

```
String word = "cheese[1]"

String definition = "[:the quality of being too obviously sentimental]"

String regex = "[^A-Za-z]+";       // how to get it to exclude whitespace?

finaldefinition = finaldefinition.replaceAll(regex,"")
```

Output:

> word = cheese
>
> definition = thequalityofbeingtooobviouslysentimental

Desired result:

> word = cheese
>
> definition = the quality of being too obviously sentimental

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Or `[^A-Za-z\s]+` if you want to keep tabs and other forms of whitespace as well.

Comment: haha thanks. It was that simple huh? /facepalm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    String[] strs = new String[] {"cheese[1]", "[:the quality of being too obviously sentimental]"};
    for (String m: strs){
        System.out.println(m.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", ""));     
}
```

Output:

```
cheese
the quality of being too obviously sentimental
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `[^A-Za-z ]+` for:

- any character,  except

  - captial letters
  - lower case letters
  - **blanks**

Or `[^A-Za-z\s]+` for:

- any character,  except

  - captial letters
  - lower case letters
  - **whitespaces** (blanks, tabs, linebreaks)

Third option: Replace `\s` to  first, so that tabs and linebraks will get blanks